# Is there a way to count sequence of 0 and 1 in R?

Tags: r, sequence, counting

I have the following data as an excel file:

| X |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 0 |

I want to count the number of times I have the following sequence:

```
00
11
10
01
```

I desire the following output:

Sequence Count

00  2
11  1
01  1
10  1

I tried using count but I could not come up with anything useful. `count.seq` serves a similar purpose but it estimates for DNA or RNA sequence data.

Comment: It's unclear how you're defining sequences. How do you get from single digits to double digits? Including some of the code you've tried would help make this process clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
x <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0)
n <- length(x)
s <- paste0(x[-n], x[-1L])
s
## [1] "00" "01" "11" "10" "00"

table(factor(s, levels = c("00", "01", "10", "11")))
## 00 01 10 11 
##  2  1  1  1
```

Comment: The previous answer (prior to the edit) worked..there seems to be a glitch in this :D

Comment: This one is more efficient, so I edited. They should both work!